# Calculating the order of two function in some group

Tags: group-theory

While studying a subject about the group operator I came across with the following question:

> Consider the following function: $h_1,h_2\,:\,\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
>    where $h_1=-x$ and $h_2=-x+1$. Lets define a new group $X=\langle h_1,
>  h_2\rangle$ which follows $X\curvearrowright\mathbb{R}$ by $h_1\cdot x
>  = h_1(x)$.
>
> Calculate $o(h_1)$ and $o(h_2)$.

Unfortunately, the books does not have final answer or solutions. I started from using the following definition of order: Let $G$ be a group, the order of $g\in G$, meaning $o(g)$ is the minimal $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $g^n=e$.

By using this definition, I understand that I need to find the minimal $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ so $h_1^n=e$ and $h_2^m=e$. But I'm not sure how to use the that $X\curvearrowright \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What books are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Hint/Explanation:

You should use the group action axioms, in particular this one:

If $g,h\in G$ elements and $G$ acts on $X$ then $$g.(h.x) = (gh).x$$

Using this you should calculate $h_1^2.x$ and $h_2^2.x$